# Unintentional Tosefes Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, mitzvah, kavana-intent

My shul newsletter misprinted candle lighting times this week --- instead of 8:01, it listed 7:48. This leads me to 2 questions:

If I light candles at 7:48 because I think that that is the right time for *shabbos*, is it still considered that I added to *shabbos* (*tosefes shabbos*)? [This](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5762/lechlecha.html) site indicates that there has to be some sort of awareness of the acceptance *l'shem* the *mitzvah* of *tosefes shabbos* (citing

> Tosefes Shabbos 261:13; Tehillah l'David 263:8-10; Chelkas Yoav 30;
>   Mishmeres Shalom 26:2; Mishnah Berurah 261:21 (as understood by Shoneh
>   Halachos 261:3; Shemiras Shabbos K'hilchasah 46:2; Az Nidberu 1:1).
>   See Ritva Rosh Hashanah 9a as a possible source.)

But I have *kavannah* to accept *shabbos* fully -- the article cited says that the *kavannah* for *tosefes shabbos* could be shown simply through candle lighting. Can I get the "credit" when I have no awareness that I am fulfilling the particular *mitzvah* but I am intentionally fulfilling a related one?

This last point calls forth whether I, as the guy making the shul bulletin can intentionally publish a wrong (too early) time so that everyone in shul gets a *schar* without trying or knowing about it. There **is** *kavannah* to perform the *mitzvah* of candles/*shabbos* but not (necessarily) *tosefes shabbos*.

Is the *mitzvah* progressive? Do I get more reward for starting even earlier? If I am already getting credit for lighting 18 minutes before sunset, is there any additional credit for lighting 30 minutes early? How early should I mislead people into lighting?

I know that this is too many questions, but they are interwoven and contingent so I'm not sure how to divide them.

Comment: If candle lighting time is already 18 minutes before, aren't you having Tosefes Shabbos in mind? You mean if you intend to do 18 minutes but instead do 31? Why do you think that would be significant?

Comment: @Yishai that's part of question two, whether it is a progressively increasing mitzvah. But if I misprint in the bulletin that CLT is 7:43 and my wife is late and lights at 8:01, she THINKS that she no longer gets tosefes shabbos and only the kavannah of shabbos, but in truth I have secured tosefes shabbos for her because in truth she is still 18 minutes early!

Comment: AFAIK, Tosfos Shabbos (by like 2 or 4 minutes) is not optional - it is a requirement. But anyway, the scenario in your comment is different than the question. As to "progressive Mitzvah", I suspect that it is more Mehudar, if anything, not necessarily a separate Mitzvah for every minute.

Comment: the scenario in my comment is an extension, depending on the answer to the questions as asked (whether one needs to have a specific type of kavannah within a larger kavannah)

Comment: I just find the question confusing - trying to point out where. Perhaps you will find ways to clarify the question (or not, it isn't always so simple to do).

Comment: @Yishai The Gra thought that Tosefet Shabbat is a Reshut IIRC (but obligatory on YK).

Comment: @DoubleAA I was about to ask regarding this point. My understanding when I read Gem. Rosh Hashanna (I think it's around daf 20?) is that this is a requirement. It makes some sense that it would be, BTW, as once the sun goes below a certain angle, one encounters doubt of actual sunset, i.e., location below the horizon. Visibility of the horizon depends on obstructions as well as altitude above sea level from my understanding. I don't recall, offhand, which of these factors were mentionedin the Gemarah.

Comment: @DanF None of that is relevant as it is just an application of Safek Deorayta leChumra. We're discussing a separate obligation to add extra time from Friday to Shabbat.

Comment: See Rashi ([*Shabbos* 118b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=118b&format=text), s.v. "ממכניסי שבת בטבריא") who indicates that the people of Tzipori and Teveria extended Shabbos due to their mistaken perception of what time it was, and that they were still praised for this (although there may be different ways to interpret this Rashi; see discussion in [*Chevel Nachalaso* 6:5](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%95_%D7%94)).